# Send data thanks to PDO protocol

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on controlling a canopen device thanks to canopen_master.
I got inspired by the canopen_chain_node but it seems that this node only use SDO protocol.
PDO management seems to be implemented in the canopen_master but I wonder how to publish a PDO frame thanks to canopen_master (maybe directly change the data in the OD?).

Is there something that i missed?

Did someone have an example of a ros_canopen SDO publisher?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231725/send-data-thanks-to-pdo-protocol/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use PDOs instead of SDOs, just configure the mapping in the EDS/DCF. ros_canopen will switch to PDO transfer automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2016-04-12**:
thank you for your answer. I have already configure the PDO mapping in my EDS and I gave the OD based on this file to my canopen::node. But when I use canopen::ObjectStorage::Entry::set() (or cached) it use SDO (I checked it with candump)

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-04-12**:
Do you use the release or the source overlay(recommended!)?
Please double check your settings. If you still cannot resolve the problem, please open a github issue and provide your settings and the candump.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2016-04-12**:
I am using the branch indigo-devel from the ros-industrial/ros_canopen repo.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2016-04-14**:
I double checked my settings and the problem was my eds file. The parsed value "Number of entries" was not set. Thank you for your help!

**Comment by [af.villamil231](https://answers.ros.org/users/40998/af.villamil231/) on 2019-05-03**:
Hello, how do you configure the mapping inside the EDS file? Once configured, to send a PDO you still have to use the srv_set_object (or srv_get_object) services or you use the socketcan_bridge package to send PDO frames? thanks!

EDIT: the answer to my second question is [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/303577/roscanopen-sdo-or-pdo-for-service-calls/?answer=303651#post-id-303651) but still, How can i do to configure the mapping inside the EDS? it sounds like I have to modify the dictionary directly but, there is a way to do it with the API? like using canopen_master package functions? Thanks

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-05-03**:
please don't post new, unrelated questions as a comment in a 3 years old question, which was already resolved.